# Comprobar si existe la $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

Quisiera comprobar en mi archivo home.php que la sessión está iniciada, y si no está que mande al usuario al login para que se identifique.
En el login tengo el `form` por POST al mismo login.php y sin base de datos.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $user = $_POST['usuario'];
   $password = $_POST['pass'];

   if (($user == "admin") AND ($password == "123456")) {
      $_SESSION['usuario'] = $user;
      header("location: home.php");
   } else {
      header("location: login.php");
   }
}
?>
```

Y en el home.php intento validar que la sessión esté iniciada para que decida llevarme de nuevo a login.php o dejarme ver el contenido. Pero siempre me está llevando a login.php

```
<?php 
    session_name('test');
    session_start();

  if ( !isset( $_SESSION['usuario'] ) ) {
    header("location: login.php");
  } 
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ese problema te ocurre porque estas utilizando `session_name()`, ya que lo que haces es:

> Obtener y/o establecer el nombre de la sesión actual

Entonces lo único que tienes que hacer para que tu código funcione es cambiar el contenido de  tu archivo `home.php` a:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header('location: login.php');
}
```

Ya con eso debe funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!